# Fetch JSON data and initialize value in data object of Vue instance

Tags: json, vue.js, lifecycle

I have a question regarding initialize value with fetched JSON in data object.
I'm using Vue-resource to get data.

```
el: '#demo',
  data: {
    locale: null,
    person: [
     {
       first_name: locale.name,
       age: locale.age,
       city: locale.city  
     }       
    ]

created: function () {
    this.fetchJson();
  },

  methods: {
    fetchJson: function () {
      var self = this;
      this.$http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/121o8p')
        .then(response => {
          self.locale = response.body;
          console.log(self.locale);
        })
    }
  },
```

JSON
{
  "name": "John",
  "age": "31",
  "city": "New York"
}

I can see the JSON data on the console but How can I initialize value of array of object with fetched JSON data?

Comment: Looks like you expect the shape of person to be of type `Array` but it is actually `Object`. Just set the `person` to an `Object` and then do `this.person = response.body` and you're done

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Thank you for quick response. I have to assign value to locale to print out the value and also initialize value with Json data into person in order to loop the elements in html. This is my codepen: [link](https://codepen.io/MachoBoy/pen/xYZMwg)

Comment: I modified your code pen and adjusted the nomenclature to more closely match what you're describing [have a look here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ddXWEd)

Comment: @ohgodwhy Thank you for your help! I got a hint from you and I found the solution :)